# In a tensor category, does $X\otimes Y\cong 0$ imply $Y\cong 0$ for non-zero $X$?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, functors

By a tensor category I mean a locally finite rigid $k$-linear abelian category with bilinear tensor product, and such that $\operatorname{Hom}(1,1)\cong k$.$^1$

> Suppose we fix some non-zero object $X$ in such a category, and we take any old object $Y$. Can we conclude from $X\otimes Y \cong 0$ that $Y$ has to be zero?

I know that in this setting the tensor product is (bi)exact. And I think the statement would be obvious if $\otimes$ would reflect isomorphisms, but I don't feel it does.

Any hints?

---

$^1$ This question really only needs *rigid abelian with bilinear $\otimes$*

Comment: No, this is already false in $\text{Vect} \times \text{Vect}$ with the pointwise tensor product.

Comment: $\mathrm{Vect}$ is fd VS I assume, what do you mean by "pointwise tensor product" - $(V_1,V_2)\otimes (W_1,W_2) \equiv (V_1\otimes W_1, V_2\otimes W_2)$? Then the zero is $(0,0)$, and with $(V,0)$ and $(0,W)$, we get $(V,0)\otimes (0,W)\cong (0,0)$, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I forgot to ping, I hope it's alright I'm doing it now. Is the above the argument you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Vect x Vect does not have End(1) = k!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coevaluation map $1 \rightarrow {}^*X \otimes X$ is non-zero, so by simplicity of $1$ it's injective.  But then by biexactness we have:
$$Y \hookrightarrow {}^*  X \otimes X \otimes Y \cong 0.$$

Comment: Thanks Noah. I think Qiaochu's commented was directed at my footnote. For your argument to work we obviously need simplicity of 1, which I dropped for some reason, I don't recall why - I usually only work in honest (finite) tensor cats.